# Kafka JDBC sink connector does not access the correct connector configurations

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a postgres running on a pi within a docker container.
Debezium connector is running on my local machine (same as zookeeper and kafka).

The kafka topic is up and running and I can see the changes which I make in the postgres going into the kafka topic. So far so good.

Now I started another docker container locally which is not from the same docker compose file as my other containers. THIS is supposed to be my REPLICA DATABASE.

I copied the confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.5.0 into the docker container.

```
sudo docker cp confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.5.0 CONTAINER_ID:/kafka/connect/
```

Changed the user and usergroup and the restated the container.

```
docker exec -it --user root <container-id> /bin/bash
chown -R <username>:<groupname> <folder/file>
```

Now I created the jdbc-sink connector.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8083/connectors/' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "piserver.public.customers",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql:192.168.128.2:5432/postgres",
        "connection.user": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "postgres",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",   
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_value"                                               
    }
}
'
```

I get back 201 created.

**The error I get is after a few seconds of running:**

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8083/connectors/jdbc-sink/status' \
--data-raw ''
```

*ERROR trace*

```
{
            "id": 0,
            "state": "FAILED",
            "worker_id": "192.168.112.4:8083",
            "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:611)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:59)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:64)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:84)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)\n\t... 10 more\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259)\n\tat java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)\n\tat java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getConnection(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:250)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect.getConnection(PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect.java:103)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:80)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:52)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)\n\tat java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)\n\tat java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)\n\t... 23 more\n"
        }
```

Short:
`Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

The hosts I tried in my config:

```
"connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql:192.168.128.2:5432/postgres" // got this IP from docker inspect POSTGRES_CONTAINER
"connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql:host.docker.internal:5432/postgres" 
"connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql:localhost:5432/postgres"
```

**None of these worked**

Always got the same error with cannot access localhost:5432.

Also tried connecting the docker postgres container(replica) to my docker-compose network.

Any thoughts on this thanks.

Small resume.

POSTGRES(on PI)->DEBEZIUM Connector(locally)-->KAFKA-> JDBC-SINK from within KAFKA -> POSTGRES( will be replica, runs locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use IP addresses between containers, and don't use localhost within containers to try to reach other containers - https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Ideally, you'd use Docker Compose to start **all services**, otherwise you need to create the network bridge yourself

```bash
docker network create database-bridge
docker run --network=database-bridge --name=postgres ...  
docker run --network=database-bridge  ... # repeat for zookeeper, kafka, and debezium
```

Or look at the networks that compose created, and attach the new container to that, since you say

> started another docker container locally which is not from the same docker compose file

```bash
docker network ls  # look for a name that matches the folder where you ran docker-compose
docker run --network=<name> ... jdbc-connector
```

Then use `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres` to connect to that container by its hostname.

If the JDBC Connector is running with `connect-distributed.sh` and not Docker, only then can you use `localhost:5432`, but you need a port mapping from the Postgres container to the host.

Comment: Putting the second Postgres seperate was on purpose. But you where correct. The docker container with just the postgres running was not connected to the same network.
`docker network connect debezium_dbz-network POSTGRES_REPLICA_NAME`
I actually tried that before. What I missed was the name, I tried the internal IP but as you mentioned use the container name! My was as sad as it is downloads_postgres_1, as i started my docker compose in the download folder.